# Getting permission denied when running docker command, even after I have been added to the docker group?

Tags: docker

I believe i have been added to a Docker group, but when I run docker, I still get a `permission denied` error.

My user is `patrick`. And when I execute `groups patrick` in my terminal, I get:

`patrick : pchong sudo docker`

Does this mean I have been added to the docker group?

WHen I try to run `docker run hello-world` I get a:

```
....sock/v1.24/containers/create": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
```

error.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

P.S. I have also tried running `sudo usermod -a -G docker patrick`, then logging in and then out of my computer, but the above error persists.

Also, when I run `grep /etc/group -e "docker"`, I get: `docker:x:140:patrick`.

Answer (score -1):

you need set the permission of the /var/run/docker.sock file to 777 to get full access  run

sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock

Comment: Remember that anyone who can get access to the Docker socket can almost trivially root the host; making the Docker socket world-writable is a terrible idea security-wise.  In general, `chmod 0777 ...` is also not the right answer even if it seems to make things work.